# Format the iCloud Timestamp

Tags: python, gps, icloud

I'm accessing the iCloud API via python with [pyiCloud](https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud).

When I pull my iPhone's GPS location with the API I get this:

```
>>> api.iphone.location()
{u'timeStamp': 1384188010186L, u'locationFinished': True, u'longitude': -0.14189, u'positionType': u'GPS', u'locationType': None, u'latitude': 51.501364, u'isOld': False, u'horizontalAccuracy': 5.0}
```

This is exactly the info I need. The issue I am having is figuring out how to convert that time stamp to something that makes sense. I'm confident that I have saw this time format before and converted it, but as of right now I can't figure it out.

I'd really like an explanation on this format, is it UTC or the ticks since 2000?

The format I am looking for something like: `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS AM/PM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://bitbucket.org/latestrevision/django-location/src/32615666b051464fa493551fc58e1f7611041252/location/management/commands/update_icloud_location.py), it appears that the timestamp is in the US/Pacific-New timezone, and you'll need to divide it by 1000.

```
local_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific-New')
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
    float(data['timeStamp']) / 1000,
    local_tz
)
```

Comment: Hmm I am in the eastern time zone. Also using your method `1384188010186L` outputs: `datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 8, 40, 10, 186000, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific-New' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)` The actual hour should be sometime like 10, 11 or 12. But I guess the time difference from Pacific to Eastern could account for this.

Comment: thanks for the help, here is what i ended up at: `import pytz
import datetime
local_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
timeStamp = api.iphone.location()
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(timeStamp['timeStamp']) / 1000, local_tz)
date.strftime("%Y%m%d %I:%M:%S %p")`